# nodejs convert image between buffer and string

Tags: node.js, image, png, buffer

i want to convert png image from `buffer` to `string`, and then convert string to buffer.

```
fs.readFile('/Users/xxx/Desktop/1.png', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.
    data = Buffer.from(data)
    let str = data.toString()
    data = Buffer.from(str)
});

// server
router.register('/api/dump', (request, response) => { 
    fs.readFile('/Users/xxx/Desktop/1.png', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read. 
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}); 
        response.end(data); // Send the file data to the browser.
    });
}) 

// front
this.$get('/dump').then(result => {
    // i want to convert result to buffer
})
```

but the new buffer is not old buffer any more.

Comment: What's the problem with the router code?, there's nothing wrong with it, it has nothing to do with the original question nor with the snippet above it.

Answer (score 6):

`Buffer.toString()` default encoding is `utf8`, and you can't convert from `utf8` back to `Buffer` without breaking the image.

If you want to convert to string, and then back to buffer, you will need to use an encoding that allows this, for example `base64`.

```
fs.readFile('/Users/yihchu/Desktop/1.png', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.
    var oldData = data;
    let str = data.toString('base64')
    data = Buffer.from(str, 'base64');
});
```

Comment: i wrote a server using nodejs, code is: router.register('/api/dump', (request, response) => {
  fs.readFile('/Users/yihchu/Desktop/1.png', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
    response.end(data); // Send the file data to the browser.
  });
}) and the response that web page received is just like toString in utf8, i want to convet it to buffer

Comment: Put that in code block, in your original question, so it can be read.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve, it seems your problem is something else.

Comment: this.$get('/dump').then(result => {
    // i want to convert result to buffer
})  the result is just like Buffer.toString('utf8'), and i want to conver to back to buffer

Comment: why, why do you need the buffer on the front end, explain what you're trying to achieve, not just "I want to convert to buffer", Why do you need the buffer.